# Is there a way to set the email hash after `pintrk('load')` has been called?

Tags: pinterest

We're implementing Enhanced Match for our React app. When a user comes to the site not logged in we call `pintrk('load')` without an email address, and then when they do login we need to provide their email address, but calling `pintrk('load')` a second time (with the email address) the library triggers an error (we don't reload the page when the user logs in).

Is there a way to set the email hash after `pintrk('load')` has been called?

Answer (score 1):

Late response but I figured this out to add for others trying to find this solution (like I was):

Use `pintrk('set', { em: EMAIL }` for setting additional information to Pinterest.